# In Adobe Acrobat Javascript, how do I search an entire PDF for all instances of amounts over 10,000?

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I wrote this:

```
for (var p=0; p<this.numPages; p++) {
    for (var n=0; n<this.getPageNumWords(p); n++) {
        var w = this.getPageNthWord(p, n);
        if  (w >= 10000) {
   console.println(w);
} else if  (w <= -10000) {
   console.println(w);
}

    }
}
```

However, it keeps giving me this error when I run it:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
1:Console:Exec
undefined
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you running the command in the Console? Unless there is a typo in your console script, I can not see a syntax error. The results may not be what you expect, getPageNthWord() returns a string, and you would have to turn it into a number, using, for example, the Number() operator.

Comment: @MaxWyss Thank you for responding. Should I change it to this?

`for (var p=0; p<this.numPages; p++) {
    for (var n=0; n<this.getPageNumWords(p); n++) {
        var w = Number(this.getPageNthWord(p, n));
        if  (w >= 10000) {
   console.println(w);
} else if  (w <= -10000) {
   console.println(w);
}

    }
}`

Comment: That should work. However, it might be an idea to add a little bit of text to the console entries, so that you can see through which path it came (it looks obvious by the value, but anything can happen).